# Why are my triangles not being drawn in the color I define?

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d-meshes

I render a simple mash structure with `Tao` (don't think this is relevant) using *DisplayList*.

Following code appears between

```
int displayList = Gl.glGenLists(1);
Gl.glNewList(displayList, Gl.GL_COMPILE);
```

and

```
Gl.glEndList();
```

Simplified version of the code, with removed unrelevant parts:

```
Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);

for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Count; i++)
{
    var triangle = triangles[i];


    bool ok = false;
    var normal = triangle.GetNormal(out ok); //get normal of TRIANGLE


  //this method just retrives correct color information here
    var visualData = GetVisualData(visual, 
                      visual.RenderSettings, triangle,null, false);


    //Set the color for the vertex here. Color is always the same in THIS case
    Gl.glColor4f(m_colors[visualData.color.R], 
                     m_colors[visualData.color.G],   
                             m_colors[visualData.color.B], 
                                 visualData.transparency);

    //for every vertex in triangle
    for (int vtx = 0; vtx < triangle.Vertices.Length; vtx++)
    {
         var v = triangles[i].Vertices[vtx];
         Vertex3 v3 = v.Coord;                 
         Gl.glVertex3d(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z); //set vertex         
         Gl.glNormal3d(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);  //set normal        

    }

}

Gl.glEnd();
```

Accoring to documentation if I set the **same** color for all 3 vertices of the triangle it must have the solid color. But what I get is:

[image: Screen shot]

As you see the colors are not uniform across different triangles, but I'm pretty sure that in *this* loop the color is not changed, it remains static (I even tried to set constant `int` values as color , but  result is always the same)

**Q**:

What can be possible reason of this rendering behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In immediate mode rendering in OpenGL, you open up a sequence of primitives by `Begin`, emit a bunch of elements in that sequence, and terminate it with `End`.

There's two choices on how OpenGL could have handled the emission of the elements. One way would be that a `Vertex` call would create an element and that subsequent calls to functions like `Color`, `Normal`, `TexCoord` would modify those attributes of that vertex.

That is not the case, however. The approach that OpenGL uses is that first you set all the attributes you want with those functions (`Color`, `Normal`, etc.), and *then* emit an immutable element with the `Vertex` function.

In your code, you do this correctly for `Color`, but your `Normal` changes are lagged by one vertex, resulting in inconsistent normals for a face.

In essence, set all the changed vertex attributes first, then invoke `Vertex` to emit a vertex with those attributes.